# Running docker -ps returns an empty list although containers are running

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

I installed docker CE version on an ubuntu 18.04 server. Then, I installed a new jenkins container and everything worked well for two weeks.

After two weeks, for some reason, when I run `docker ps` I receive an empty list although the jenkins container is running and functioning (it worked in the past). I also tried to run `docker ps -a`, `docker images` and again, everything is empty. Also tried restarting the server and still every time the list is empty.

I then uninstalled and reinstalled docker and right after the installation, when running `docker ps` I see the containers....I thought that the problem was fixed, but today it happened to me again and I still see an empty list when running `docker ps`. Any ideas ? it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run a system upgrade between the moment it works and the moment it stops working ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no, I didn't...maybe it is run automatically. But in any way, can it cause such an issue?

Comment: You can use
```
docker info|grep 'Docker Root Dir'
```
check the **Docker Root Dir** is change?

Comment: Docker runs some post-kernel operations each time it is updated. As example, on my machine I have to reload kernel modules each time I update my kernel to make docker work again (but running containers are not affected). I don't know if it could cause your issue, but it may be useful to know to help you resolve it.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, how do you reload the modules? you need to run a specific cli command ?

Comment: How many instances of `dockerd` are running on your host? Have you installed docker different ways (snap, OS vendor version, docker upstream version)?

Comment: I have 2 containers running. I installed the official version. If you have any recommendations of any specific installation it is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `sudo service docker stop`

After that find the process dockerd

`ps aux | grep "dockerd"`

and kill the one by

`sudo kill {paste_dockerd_pid_here} -9`

Start docker service

`sudo service docker start`